# Reading uncommitted data inside transaction (MS SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have written a program in C# to read data from to tables, transform it and write it to four other tables.

Three of the destination tables has an not null integer pointing to the primary key on the last destination table. I call this V.

When my program have read a chunk of data to memory and transformed it, it will use the SqlBulkCopy to write to the table V. Upon completion it will use a select-statement to retrieve the primary keys.

These primary keys will be assigned properly to the three other destination tables in memory. Finally the last three tables will be written to the database using SqlBulkCopy in one transaction.

However, if the program writes successfully to the table V, but fails to write the other three tables I have a bunch of dirty data.

Can I somehow map the data going into table V with their primary keys, inside a transaction surrounding the all the code?

I would be sincerely happy for any suggestion to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Place a foreign key on the three tables' columns that are referring back to the primary key on table V.  That will make certain there is no dirty data.  You may have to rework your logic and the order the tables are written in, but adding the foreign key should clean up the process and make it work smoother after refactoring.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. That is why I need to read the primary keys from table V, so I can give them to the other tables.

My trouble is to do this in a transaction.

Comment: What is preventing you from doing all the writes in a single transaction?  If you are using a foreign key you should be able to perform the initial set of writes, attempt the second set, and if the original table values weren't written the second set's attempt to write should fail on the rows that would have caused a primary key violation.

Comment: I have to make the relations after I write table V to the database. Only then do I know the primary keys on table V, and only upon knowing these can I relate the tables T, Q and W to V.

I do this:
1) Write to V (in database)
2) Read primary keys from V 
3) Write foreign keys to T, Q and W (in memory)
4) Write to T, Q and W (in database)

I worry about senarios where (1) completes but (4) does not.

I thank you for your interest.

Comment: I believe I understand now.  Every entry in table V should have at least one entry in tables T, Q and W.  You are worried that when the writes to tables T, Q, and W fail in a transaction there will be the entry in V, which is invalid without the appropriate entries in T, Q, and W.  One solution might be, in your C# code, to monitor the transaction that adds the entries to tables T, Q and W and if it fails then  delete the original entry in V.

Comment: That is better than doing nothing, but it won't help in a senario there the problem fails and terminate.

Comment: What about using a view when referencing the data?  You could only expose the "complete" records in the view and filter out entries in V where there are no corresponding entries in T, Q and W.  Another suggestion might be to have another process or scheduled task that cleans out invalid entries every so often.